# Distributed rest calls and aggregrate

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, distributed

I have a use case for client that needs to load large data from a web rest service. This rest api is highly scalable and there is apparently no issues on handling more than 10000+ concurrent requests.

My issue is, I have a need to use this service concurrently (1000 requests) and load large data in a short time.

Issues:

```
1) Each request can return about 10-30MB of compressed json data.
2) My machine can't afford to make 1000+ requests on a 8 core 32G machine due to each thread blockking IO function
3) I'm looking for a distributed method to do this.
4) The service does provide pagination but this is very slow
5) I need a synchronous solution
```

I have tried AMS services and looking for something like hadoop to do this. Although my code looks for an API to wrap around this rest service to do this kind of large data load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 8v32g machine can only do so little as much as concurrent 8 threads executing rest API calls. You should be looking for a horizontal scalable solution and keep in mind what you want to do with 1000 * 30 (30G of Compressed data).

Apache Livy is a rest service across spark like you mentioned which is able to run each of your task being hitting your rest service and receiving 30MB of json data.

Check here for Apache Livy : `http://livy.apache.org/` . This is still in incubating but it is available in AWS. Might not recommend for an enterprise solution but this is what you probably are looking for!

Comment: lking 4 an entrerprise solution in the future. i have already implemented RPC instead and directly invoke calls to the db than hit the service! Thanks for the solution